# Setting default model conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a condition on which most of my models will have to adhere when retrieving data.

This condition will be the id of the company to which the user logged in. So for instance, let's say the company id is 1, then all the information relating to company_id 1 must show.

How can I set a default condition to my models?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this code

```
class FooModel extends AppModel {

    protected $_companyId = null;

    public function setCompanyId($companyId) {
        // Optional validation of the id here
        $this->_companyId = $companyId;
    }

    public function beforeFind($query) {
        if (!empty($this->_companyId)) {
            $query['conditions'][$this->alias . '.company_id'] = $this->_companyId;
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

To *decouple* it from the models I would suggest you to implement these two methods in a behavior and attach it to only the models that need it.

**Edit, here as behavior:**

```
class CompanyFilterBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

    protected $_companyId = null;

    public function setCompanyId(Model $Model, $companyId) {
        // Optional validation of the id here
        $this->_companyId = $companyId;
    }

    public function beforeFind(Model $Model, $query) {
        if (!empty($this->_companyId)) {
            $query['conditions'][$Model->alias . '.company_id'] = $this->_companyId;
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

In your AppController you can do this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->User->loggedIn() 
        && $this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->loaded('CompanyFilter'))
    {
        $this->{$this->modelClass}->setCompanyId($this->Auth->user('company_id'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, although I would call `setCompanyId()` inside `beforeFilter()` on `FooController`

Comment: Well, you can do $this->{$this->modelClass}->setCompanyId(...); in the beforeFilter of each controller that needs it. If you do that in AppController you'll get issues. You need to wrap it in a check if the model implements the method or as I proposed the behavior is loaded.

Comment: Although this is a very good answer, it doesn't work. It works for a `belongsTo` relation, but not a `hasMany`. After a bit of cheating, I got it working though. Created an if in my behavior to check if it has a `belongsTo` or `hasMany` relation and either changes the query, or does an on the fly `bind`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain much info at all, so be more precise the next time and people answering you can take all factors in consideration... Would you mind flagging it as correct?