# user_id condition on all models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to develop an app with multiple users. Each users have for example their own clients, invoices, settings, profile etc.

By default the CakePHP generated Controllers/Models/Views will show all clients, invoices etc beloning to all users.

So I have to edit the add,view,index,edit and delete actions so that users only can view,edit,add,delete their own clients,invoices,settings,profile etc.

I am wondering if there is any easier more general way to do this. Like doing it in the AppController.php or AppModel.php so that it is not needed to do it for each Controller/Model/View.

Or if CakePHP automatically can do this since the hasMany, belongsTo etc properties are correctly set.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/05/common-cakephp-problems-and-solutions/) helps. You can add a user_id filter to your model find() for specific actions making only the records visible that this user is affiliated with etc. PS: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have been doing. But I have to do this for every new controller and action that I make. My question is if there is any easier "prettier" way to do this. Best way would be if cake could automatically do this based on the hasMany, belongsTo etc parameters.

Comment: Well, you can write a behavior of something. Other than that you would probably need to provide (more) code in order to get a more detailed answer to this question.

Comment: Seems like behavior will work. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there `$order` like public variable called `$conditions` for every model? I can not find any documentation on this, not even about the `$order` variable of which I know it exists! Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The same question has already been asked by someone and answered by me in detail here: [Setting default model conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173230/setting-default-model-conditions)

It includes a behavior example as well.

Comment: If it's a dupe, vote to close.  Don't add an answer stating it's a dupe.